# How to remove arc border in shadowed UIView with rounded / arc path?

Tags: swift, uibezierpath, rounded-corners

I have ticket View like this

[image: TicketView].

My method is I have 2 view, 1 is the ticket itself, and other is for shadow. I have to do this because if I mask the view, it got clipped and the shadow will not appear in the ticket view.

here is the code for create the ticket view:

```
let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer.frame = someView.bounds
shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: someView.bounds,
                               byRoundingCorners: [UIRectCorner.bottomLeft,UIRectCorner.bottomRight] ,
                               cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 5.0, height: 5.0)).cgPath


let rect = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:200, height:100)
let cornerRadius:CGFloat = 5
let subPathSideSize:CGFloat = 25

let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: cornerRadius)
let leftSubPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: rect.width / 2, y: 0),
                               radius: subPathSideSize / 2, startAngle: .pi, endAngle: .pi * 0, clockwise: false)
leftSubPath.close()

let rightSubPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: rect.width / 2, y: rect.height),
                                radius: subPathSideSize / 2, startAngle: .pi, endAngle: .pi * 0, clockwise: true)
rightSubPath.close()

path.append(leftSubPath)
path.append(rightSubPath.reversing())

let mask = CAShapeLayer()
mask.frame = shapeLayer.bounds
mask.path = path.cgPath
someView.layer.mask = mask
```

*Notes: `SomeView` is the `TicketView`.*

And here is the code for adding shadow:

```
let shadowMask = CAShapeLayer()
shadowMask.frame = shadowView.bounds
shadowMask.path = path.cgPath
shadowMask.shadowOpacity = 0.2
shadowMask.shadowRadius = 4
shadowMask.masksToBounds = false
shadowMask.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2)

shadowView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
shadowView.layer.addSublayer(shadowMask)
```

The shadow makes arc/rounded corner have border like this one (marked with circle red).

[image: view with border on corner]

Here is my [Playground gist](https://gist.github.com/jeffersonsetiawan/54d65dc5a9f03b456c3702d10f4de463)

Do you know how to remove the border in the rounded corner and arc path?

Thank you.

Comment: Please add _relevant_ code to the question, not via a link

Comment: done @AshleyMills

Comment: I've already using separate view dedicated for the shadow @TamásSengel

Answer (score 1):

u need to add clipToBounds in this block that you have written.

```swift
let mask = CAShapeLayer()
mask.frame = shapeLayer.bounds
mask.path = path.cgPath
someView.clipsToBounds = true
someView.layer.mask = mask
```

Answer (score 0):

So I think there is different calculation for corner in mask and path. So I used fillColor of the shadowLayer to match the color of the CouponView. And now, the borders are gone.

`shadowLayer.fillColor = someView.backgroundColor.cgColor`